# How to approach series (and sums) like those?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Whats the right test to approach series like these, I spend ages but found none that are similar.
$a_k=\frac{(k+1)^k}{(-k)^k}$ and
$a_k=\frac{k+2^k}{k\cdot 2^k}$
those two have me stumped the ratio and root-test yield nothing. How to procced, any tips greatly appreciated!

Thank you both very helpful, can I conclude from this that the sums of those series are divergent?
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_k=\frac{(k+1)^k}{(-k)^k} $ and
$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_k=\frac{k+2^k}{k\cdot 2^k}$ ?

Comment: For the first, what is the most fundamental test for convergence? For the second one, try splitting into two terms.

Comment: For the second if I split it like Jacobi Matrix suggested  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_k=\frac{k+2^k}{k\cdot 2^k}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {k}$, then the second sum is the harmonic Series which diverges, is this enough to conclude the whole Sum diverges (like for Series)?

Comment: If the first series converges and the second diverges, their sum cannot converge

Comment: Is this also true for infinite sums?

Answer (score 0):

For thew first
$$\left|\frac{(k+1)^k}{(-k)^k}\right|= \left|\frac{k+1}{k}\right|^k\ge 1 $$
so $a_k:=\frac{(k+1)^k}{(-k)^k}\not\to 0$ (recall $a_k\to0\iff|a_k|\to0$) and the series cannot converges.

For the second, observe that
$$a_k:=\frac{k+2^k}{k2^k}=\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{k}$$
If it were convergent, then $\frac{1}{k}=a_k-\frac{1}{2^k}$ would be a convergent series, since both $a_k$ and $\frac{1}{2^k}$ were. But this is a contradiction. So the series $a_k$ cannot converges.

Comment: Is $ a_k$ not going to zero also enough to conclude the infinite sum diverges? Or only the other way round

Comment: If $\sum a_k$ converges then $a_k\to0$ ($a_k=\sum_{j=1}^k a_j -\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} a_j$). Take the contra-reciprocal

Comment: What does contra-reciprocal mean? $ \neg a_n \Rightarrow 0 \implies \neg \sum{a_k} $ does converge right? So it's enough to show that  if $ \neg a_n \Rightarrow 0) \implies \sum{a_k} $ diverges $, because not converge and diverge are the same?

Comment: $(A\to B)\longleftrightarrow (\neg B\to\neg A)$. In this case, $A=$"the series converges" and $B=$"the general term goes to zero".

Comment: So the "general term does not go to zero" implies "the series does not converge" and not converge is the same as divergence correct? Thank you

Comment: Sorry still confused! you write $ \frac{1}{k}$ is not convergent but as a sequence it is and we are working with sequences to prove the sequence of $ a_k \rightarrow 0 $ to show the sum is not convergent?

Comment: Just a minute.... Are you speaking about SERIES (infinite sums) or about SEQUENCES?

Answer (score 0):

For the first one we can factor out the $k$ in the numerator and denominator like $$\frac{(k+1)^k}{(-k)^k}=\frac{(k(1+\frac{1}{k}))^k}{(k(-1))^k}=\frac{(1+\frac{1}{k})^k}{(-1)^k}$$
It is well known that the series in the numerator converges to $e$ and the one in the denominator diverges thus the whole sequence diverges by the calculation rules for the limit.
For the second one we observe that $$\frac{k+2^k}{k2^k}=\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{k}$$ again here it is  a well known fact that both these sequences converge to zero as $k$ goes to infinity thus by the rules for the limit the sum converges to zero.